# Fallback image with condition on error in Ionic 2 Angular 4

Tags: angular, image, ionic2, src, ng-template

I have a  tag which hold an image source. I also wrote an error case if the image fails. Below is my code

```
<div class="column thumbnail"><img class="posterThumbNail" [src]="item.imageUrl" onError="this.src='./assets/imgs/placeholder.png';" /></div>
```

Can I have a condition inside this onError so that, depending on the thumbnail category, I can show different placeholder image with respect to the category. Expecting something like,

```
<div class="column thumbnail"><img class="posterThumbNail" [src]="item.imageUrl" onError="errorPlaceHolder" /></div>

<ng-template #errorPlaceHolder>
 <div [ngSwitch]="item.category">
    <template [ngSwitchCase]="foo">
        <div>./assets/imgs/placeholderFoo.png</div>
    </template>
    <template [ngSwitchCase]="bar">
        <div>./assets/imgs/placeholderBar.png</div>
    </template>
    <template [ngSwitchCase]="cat">
        <div>./assets/imgs/placeholderCat.png</div>
    </template>¯
    <template [ngSwitchCase]="dog">
        <div>./assets/imgs/placeholderDog.png</div>
    </template>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

I know the above code in syntactically not correct. I am looking for solution matching my above snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also reverse the logic and replace the placeholder only when the main image is loaded. This can be done with ngif and (load). Also how about putting the logic in the class instead of in the template? Easier to debug?
It can be finished with a help on an additional array to keep the track of loaded images. This array could be merged with the original array, depending how you get it and how you manage it.

**Class:**

```
loaded = [false, false, false]; // should have items length
...
getReplacementImage(category) {
switch (category) {
  case "dog":
    return "dogImage";
  case "cat":
    return "catImage"
  default:
    return "placeholderImage"
}
```

**Html:**

```
<... *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">

    <img [class.image-error]="!loaded[i]" ... [src]="item.image" (load)='loaded[i]=true'>

    <img *ngIf="!loaded[i]" ... [src]="getReplacementImage(item.category)">

</...>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-error {
  display:none; // to hide the placeholder image
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppbjgt)

Comment: This is a awesome approach. But in my case the list is builded already which has more items. Image is a part and I cannot handle in a way you did propose.

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks. One change i need to do is, can I hide the first <img> in case of error using something like "class.error". I cannot use the css as such. It is distorting my UI. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I also did with "ngStyle". Thanks a lot for the quick solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a ts side variable which sets the errorPath.

```
errorPaths:string[]=[];

//set the path wherever you receive item
switch(item.category){
  //set the path for each case in loop

}
```

In your html file,

```
 <div ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
    <div class="column thumbnail"><img class="posterThumbNail" [src]="item.imageUrl" [onError]="errorPaths[i]" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mine is a list item placed inside ngFor. If any <img> having 'src' fails, appropriate placeholder image needs to be shown. Can I have ts side switch case work in my case ?

Comment: You could.  But you will have to have an array of errorPaths

Comment: Or have an errorPath attribute in item if possible and set them

Comment: I can have array of error path. But I am not clear in how can to map the switch case with <img> 'src' in run time and on Error

Answer (score 0):

You should use (error) event to handle error and according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893194/fallback-image-with-condition-on-error-in-ionic-2-angular-4) you can use object to display fallback image

HTML:

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
  ...

  <img *ngIf="!item.fallbackUrl" class="posterThumbNail" [data]="item.imageUrl" (error)="handleError(item)" />

  <img *ngIf="item.fallbackUrl" class="posterThumbNail" [src]="item.placeHolder" />

  ...

  </div>
```

Controller:

```
handleError(item: any) {
  switch (item.category) {
    case "foo":
      item.fallbackUrl = './assets/imgs/placeholderFoo.png';
      break;
    case "bar":
      item.fallbackUrl = './assets/imgs/placeholderBar.png';
      break;
    default:
  }

}
```

Comment: But in my case, i cannot determine if there is an error or not when loading the items. If the image source fails, then placeholder image needs to be placed and am looking to have appropriate placeholder image matching my business logic. Also, it is an list item placed inside ngFor. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I edit the solution with ngFor loop, just attach the "error" flag to your item object. Sorry but I don't understand why you say you cannot determine if there is an error, this is what (error) event do for you.... Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You are correct. I meant I cannot catch the error in TypeScript code since it got bind in <img> in html.  Also as I said the code which I posted is syntactically not correct. In the code you provided, if ( item.error = true ) then how to map the fallback image path to the img src. I just placed a div in ngSwitch inside ng-template which didn't work.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your switch statement, now I better understand. I have edited my answer, hope it can help!

Comment: But "item" does not a property error and we are not changing the value of the property anywhere. It is not working. Also trying to understand more on your solution.

Comment: Sorry for the misnaming, i  have renamed property as fallbackUrl for better understanding. Even if it is not a property of your item type, it should work by typing item as any in handleError function